# Regex doesn't match expected symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex to match only digits and some specific symbols. `/[()\-\+ \d]/g`

I try this regex with [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com/) and it match all expected symbols.

In my app i use this regex to check if user input into textbox only allowed symbols. And here is problem as only digits, space and `()` are allowed according to regex.

My code : **http://jsfiddle.net/r6e8axsr/**

Comment: show your code and the examples you tried to match

Answer (score 1):

You need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the regex to the start and end of the string, and allow more than a single character to match. If you don't, the regex will succeed as long as there is at least one of the allowed characters in your string.

```
if (/^[()+ \d-]*$/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: some comments : should i add "\" symbol before plus `+` and `-` ? because `-` is recognized as interval. If i do so, minus and plus are not allowed whether `^&` etc are.

Comment: @vks, please check this example http://jsfiddle.net/r6e8axsr/3/ . I do as Tim said + your comment - but i can't input minus,plus, while $%^ etc i can

Comment: @vks, it alos doesn't help. `/^[()+ \d-]*$/m` i can't see any difference in result

Comment: @demo: First, you don't need to escape `+` in a character class, and `-` only needs to be escaped if it's not at the start or end of the class. Second, this regex returns `true` if `subject` contains only the characters `()+- 0123456789`. This includes the empty string. If you don't want to match the empty string, replace `*` with `+`.

Comment: Tim, i believe you, but on example it doesn't behave correctly http://jsfiddle.net/r6e8axsr/4/ Or i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hi (a little bit late to the party),

**TL;DR:** use `var key = event.key;`

The problem was never on the regex itself.
At the time of your writing, you could've used another event handler, using **keypress** instead of keydown would've worked, because **keypress** gives you a character code, not a key code.

But nowadays keypressed is deprecated, so using **keydown** is fine, but nowadays **event.key** has good browser support so you can just use:

`var key = event.key;`
instead of
`var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);`

Also the **value** logic on your code is not necessary as **value** is undefined everytime.